# how to use ng-repeat for array items in object which is inside other object in single ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, key-value

having data as:

```
{  
  "obj1":{  
    "obj11":[  
     {  
        "name":"Tim",
        "roll_number":"45"
     },
     {  
        "name":"Tom",
        "roll_number":"20"
     },
     {  
        "name":"Deny",
        "roll_number":"42"
     }
    ],
    "obj12":[  
     {  
        "name":"Jim",
        "roll_number":"43"
     },
     {  
        "name":"Crook",
        "roll_number":"46"
     },
     {  
        "name":"Michael",
        "roll_number":"48"
     }
    ]
  }
}
```

having keys "obj11" and "obj12" , want to ng-repeat a specific block of HTML code for items corresponding to these specific keys inside obj1. This repeated block basically contains 'name' and 'roll_number' corresponding to each object in array.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in obj1['keyValue']">
  <p>{{item.name}}</p>
  <p>{{item.roll_number}}</p>
</div>
```

if keyValue is 'obj11', output is :

Tim

45

Tom

20

Deny

42

Answer (score 0):

Assign `keyValue` to a `$scope` variable, then use it without the quotes:

```
ng-repeat="item in obj1[keyValue]"
```

JS:

```
$scope.keyValue = "obj12";
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot traverse both obj11 and obj12 using single ng-repeat. since both obj11 and obj12 are further nested. You need a nested ng-repeat as follows. Considering the entire json to be assigned to some variable "data":

```
<div ng-repeat="item in data.obj1">
  <div ng-repeat="a in item">
    <p>{{a.name}}</p>
    <p>{{a.roll_number}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('HomeCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.keyValue = "obj11";

  $scope.obj1 = {
    "obj11": [{
      "name": "Tim",
      "roll_number": "45"
    }, {
      "name": "Tom",
      "roll_number": "20"
    }, {
      "name": "Deny",
      "roll_number": "42"
    }],
    "obj12": [{
      "name": "Jim",
      "roll_number": "43"
    }, {
      "name": "Crook",
      "roll_number": "46"
    }, {
      "name": "Michael",
      "roll_number": "48"
    }]
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>


<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="HomeCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="item in obj1[keyValue]">
    <p>{{item.name}}</p>
    <p>{{item.roll_number}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Rather than doing `obj1['keyValue']` which means the key is literal value `keyValue`, bind it as a scope variable.

So, set `$scope.keyValue = "obj11";` where value is the key.
And then access it like `obj1[keyValue]` in the `ng-repeat`

Answer (score 0):

One of the many ways you can accomplish what you want.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  
  $scope.item = {
    "myItems": {
      "child1": [{
        "name": "Tim",
        "roll_number": "45"
      }, {
        "name": "Tom",
        "roll_number": "20"
      }, {
        "name": "Deny",
        "roll_number": "42"
      }],
      "child2": [{
        "name": "Jim",
        "roll_number": "43"
      }, {
        "name": "Crook",
        "roll_number": "46"
      }, {
        "name": "Michael",
        "roll_number": "48"
      }]
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  
  <select ng-model="key">
    <option ng-repeat="(key,val) in item.myItems" value="{{key}}">{{key}}</option>
  </select>

  <div ng-repeat="item in item.myItems[key]">
    <p>{{item.name}}</p>
    <p>{{item.roll_number}}</p>
  </div>
</body>
```